# Python code to extend a list of prime numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

I want to write code that extends a list of prime numbers using Python, but something does not work:

```
list = [2,3,5,7]

for num in range(15,30):
    for i in range(0,len(list)-1):
        if num%list[i] != 0:
            if i + 1 == len(list):
                list.append(num)
            else:
                continue
        else:
            break

print(list)
```

The incorrect output is: [2, 3, 5, 7]

Comment: And presumably this code you have posted does not work in some way? What output are you getting? What output were you expecting?

Comment: It should be `for i in range(0,len(list)):`. Also, what about 11 and 13?

Comment: All primes greater than 3 are of the form 6n-1 or 6n+1.  You can speed up your search by only looking at numbers of those two forms.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that

```
for i in range(0,len(list)-1):
```

should be

```
for i in range(0,len(list)):
```

The `range` function in python will stop on the number before the number you specify in the *stop* argument, so you don't need to minus 1 yourself. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range):

*For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and **r[i] < stop.***

Answer (score 0):

Because your code doesn´t work.
If you run your code, you will see that the program jumps in the `else` part of your first `if` condition and there you will break the `for` loop. So your program does nothing other than deklaring a list and print that list, because the true part of the `if` condition isn´t processed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix the issue @RobStreeting pointed out (+1) is to get rid of the `range(len())` idiom and use `enumerate()`.  We can fix the missing 11 & 13 that @ThierryLathuille points out by starting our loop just afer the last collected prime.  Finally, you shouldn't have a variable named `list` as that's a reserved Python keyword.  Putting this all together, your code looks something like:

```
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7]

for number in range(primes[-1] + 1, 50):
    for i, prime in enumerate(primes, start=1):
        if number % prime:
            if i == len(primes):
                primes.append(number)
            else:
                continue
        else:
            break

print(*primes, sep=", ")
```